# jquery generate random number for div height and width

Tags: jquery

I want to generate a random numbers using div width and height.After generating ,i've to place a static text using x and y position but text should not over lap.

This function will generate a random number for me `Math.floor ( Math.random ( ) );` but say i want n numbers can it always assure me that the text will not overlap on each other.

How do i generate random numbers using height and width ?

Comment: It sounds like you are asking two different things. By definition, you can't *guarantee* that two randomly generated numbers won't be the same. They're *random* (or pseudo-random anyway, but close enough). If you want non-overlapping elements, you can't solely use random numbers. Use the css `top` and `left` properties, along with each element's width and height, to calculate if it will overlap with any previous elements before adding it. Then you can just keep generating random numbers until it fits in I suppose...give it a try, then revise your question if you have a more specific problem!

Comment: @nbrooks:How do i do using top and left ? I've to place text inside an div,at first nothing will be there.

Comment: `$(element).css('top')` is one way, `$(element).offset().top` is another. The latter is probably what you need in this case (the first doesn't necessarily retrieve the number. See [jQuery .offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset)

Comment: @nbrooks:Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/q58HK/5/ but it is over lapping.

Comment: Well I did suggest that you *"keep generating random numbers until it fits in"*...anyway I've implemented that below :)

Comment: @nbrooks:Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/q58HK/7/

Comment: Yes...? If you put 1000 elements there it becomes *impossible* to fit them all without some overlaps (which is why the alert pops up, to let you know randomizing failed). This will only work if you have enough space to fit all of the elements. If each element has a certain width and height and your screen is of limited area, it's fairly easy to figure out how many elements you can fit. You can also tweak the fault tolerance to allow slight overlaps, like I mentioned in my post.

Comment: @if i change my width to 790 in css and also random ,how to make sure every things gets filled.Instead of text ,if i put small image will that fit correctly w/o over lapping.Thanks a lot for this.http://jsfiddle.net/q58HK/10/

Answer (score 0):

```
x=Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
y=Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
$('#idoftextbox').val('X Position is '+x+' and Y Position is '+y);
```

Comment: `Math.floor(Math.random())` *always* returns `0`. Try it. `Math.Random()` returns a number between 0 and 1, and flooring that will always round it down to 0

Comment: @Man Programmer:Is that 1000 height and width that i should put up there.

Answer (score 0):

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/q58HK/6/)

Here is your updated code with handling for text clashes; you need to modify the clash tolerance distance (and perhaps the number of random tries before giving up) depending on your text. While terribly inefficient theoretically, there aren't currently any noticeable performance issues, but you can tweak as needed.

One obvious performance boost would be keeping the coordinate lists in sorted order. That way, you wouldn't have to check against each previous value in each list before making each insertion, and searching for the correct index to insert at would be the same process as checking for a clash. For that matter you could change `isTooClose` from `O(n)` to `O(log n)` simply by using a better search algorithm, which you can find easily.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var z = 300, tops = [], lefts = [];

    for (var i = 0; i <= z; i++) {
        var x=0, y=0, j=0;
        while( isTooClose(x, y) && j < 50) {
            x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
            y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
            j++;
        }
        if (j>=50) { alert('1'); }
        $('<div>').css({
            position: "absolute",
            left: x,
            top: y,
            fontSize: 'small'
        }).html("Hello").appendTo('#test');
        lefts.push(x);
        tops.push(y);
    }

    function isTooClose( x, y ) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tops.length; i++) {
            if ( (x + 30 >= lefts[i] && x - 30 <= lefts[i]) &&
                 (y + 10 >= tops[i] && y - 10 <= tops[i]) ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

​

Comment: :If i increase my height and width,how do i make sure every things get filled.http://jsfiddle.net/q58HK/8/

Comment: @redasaw Width corresponds to the x-coordinate...you made the width bigger but changed the range for y instead. See correction: http://jsfiddle.net/q58HK/9/

Comment: :perfect but why is my text outside my div ?

Comment: @redasaw Your border is taking up part of the space for the div, and the rest is because the stating position of the text is still in the div, but the content itself isn't restricted to that. The random numbers are guaranteed to to be in the div, but that only corresponds to the top-left corner of your text. To fix this, you can restrict your random number range to ensure that the text can fit fully in the div given a certain start point (subtract ~30 from left, ~15 from top)

Comment: :After changing to -15 from left,it is still out of my div.

Comment: Like this? Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/q58HK/11/. Note that since the corners are still in the range, words might appear there. You will probably just need to handle this manually, by writing a new `inCorner` function. Then you check if the x-value is at one of the two extremes AND the y-value is also at one of the two extremes. Take a look at how I wrote the `isTooClose` function, and try to write this yourself

Comment: :if i've to display image for each text.What should i use? .html('<img src="g.jpg">').Is it correct ? If the string size varies for eg: i've a string like this sdffffffffffffff then how to maintain space with out over lap.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17229/discussion-between-nbrooks-and-redasaw)

Comment: :How do i pass my string length and my all images would be same only my text will change.